# INSERT linked data to linked tables at once

Tags: sql, insert, linked-tables

I'm trying to write a SQL. I want to add data to 2 linked tables. The data which will be written in these 2 tables are taken from 2 different tables and these are also linked. There are 3 rows in the first table and 9 rows in second table. I need to transfer them to the other 2 linked tables. I'm using C# for programming

Main Source table (S1):

```
ID    TYPE   STATUS
1015    12        2
1016    12       10
1021    12        4
```

Child source table (S2) Linked by UID:

```
ID      UID     PRODUCTREF   AMOUNT
1090    1015    1268          2
1091    1015    1269          5
1093    1016    1269          2
1094    1016    1270          2
1096    1016    1271          5
1097    1015    268           4
1098    1016    269          10
1099    1021    1268         12
1100    1021    269           3
```

Destination table sample after run SQL like this:

Main destination table (D1):

```
ID     STATUS
1      2
2      10
3      4
```

Child destination table (D2) Linked by REFID:

```
ID   REFID     PRODUCTREF   AMOUNT
1    1         1268          2
2    1         1269          5
3    2         1269          2
4    2         1270          2
5    2         1271          5
6    1         268           4
7    2         269          10
8    3         1268         12
9    3         269           3
```

Is it possible at once? How to do if it is not possible at once?

Thanks...

Edit:

I tried a transaction query but failed

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
DECLARE @DataID int; 
INSERT INTO D1 STATUS SELECT STATUS FROM S1 AS S1;
SELECT @DataID = SCOPE IDENTITY(); 
INSERT INTO D2 (REFID, PRODUCTREF, AMOUNT) SELECT @DataID, PRODUCTREF, AMOUNT FROM S2 
WHERE UID = S1.ID 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: it is not possible.  you can only update one table at a time.  you can do it in a single unit of work called a transaction.  read about transactions

Comment: Can you show it on a sample transaction?

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: You told me to read about transactions on first comment. So I asked if you can show it through the example.

Comment: I guess I could show you an example but what I suggested is you read some documentations about transactions.  Did you do that?

Comment: I tried a transaction above but i failed.

Comment: I think i must solve problem programmatically.

Comment: I would hope so, it is a computer